# (Python)How do I make a function to count the amount of specific numbers in a randomized list?

Tags: python, random

My program is to create a randomized list of 1-10 for a range of 1000, each number has to be randomized through 1-10 then once that is done. I need to identify how many 1s, 2s,3s, and 4,s, etc there are in the 1000 randomized numbers.

```
import random
#Printing a random list of 1 through 10
#loop to loop 1000 times
for i in range(1000):
  #lisitng random numbers 1 through 10 inclusive 
  l1 = random.randint(1, 10)
  l2 = random.randint(1, 10)
  l3 = random.randint(1, 10)
  l4 = random.randint(1, 10)
  l5 = random.randint(1, 10)
  l6 = random.randint(1, 10)
  l7 = random.randint(1, 10)
  l8 = random.randint(1, 10)
  l9 = random.randint(1, 10)
  l10 = random.randint(1, 10)
  #printing the numbers in a list form 
  print(l1,l2,l3,l4,l5,l6,l7,l8,l9,l10)
  #A  function to identify how many X are there in each number
```

If you need more information on this please tell me in the comments.

Comment: this should help:

https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_list_count.asp

Comment: You seem to know the APIs to use, but you forgot to actually try to make a `list`, or count anything. I'd suggest running through a Python tutorial to actually learn Python before asking other people to write your code/do your homework for you. Learn enough to try this yourself, and if you can't make it work, provide a [MCVE] for us to assist with; we can't teach you all of Python from scratch, question by question.

Comment: You should use a list instead of `l1` - `l10`.

Comment: Thanks for the information, I apologize for asking very basic questions, I will try to research more on my behalf and thanks for the link.

Answer (score 4):

First you need to generate the list, simplest way to do this is like so:

```
randomList = [random.randint(1, 10) for x in range(1, 1000)]
```

Next you need to count how many of each number there are in that array, you can do that like this:

```
randomCounts = [ (x, randomList.count(x)) for x in range(1, 10)]
```

This will output an array of tupples, where the first value of the tuple represents a number, and the second represents how often that number occurs in the randomList.

You could then do something like this to find how often the number N occured in that list:

```
amount = randomCounts[n - 1][1]
```

Comment: @DanielHao thats odd, it did work for me. maybe you misunderstood the form in which i parse the result? i get an output similair to this: [(1, 116), (2, 88), (3, 110), (4, 98), (5, 91), (6, 100), (7, 94), (8, 111), (9, 90)]

Comment: I added a bit to my explanation where i explain how to find the counts of the number n, hope that clairified it

Comment: Thanks~  @Luke, it did help - not sure what's got mixed-up... Works now.

Answer (score 2):

This should do the trick:

```
import random

random_list = []

for i in range(1000):
    random_list.append(random.randint(1, 10))

for i in range(10):
    print("{} was in the list exactly {} times.".format(i+1, random_list.count(i+1)))
```

Comment: very correct. You may consider using a comprehension (i.e. random_list = [random.randint(1, 10) for i in range (1000)]) but that answer is not meaningfully different from yours

Comment: I know but for new Python programmers this is more readable :) + the other answer already post it.

Answer (score 1):

Use  `collections.Counter` to tally the occurrences of each number, and use `random.choices` to create your random numbers within a range:

```
from collections import Counter
from random import choices

counter = Counter(choices(range(1, 10 + 1), k=1000))

for key, value in sorted(counter.items()):
    print(f"Number of {key}s: {value}")
```

Output:

```
Number of 1s: 87
Number of 2s: 102
Number of 3s: 93
Number of 4s: 116
Number of 5s: 109
Number of 6s: 79
Number of 7s: 105
Number of 8s: 105
Number of 9s: 104
Number of 10s: 100
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems you want to:

1. create a list of 1000 items where each item can be a random integer in the range from 1 to 10.
2. count how many of each integer there are in that list.

So, let's create a list of 1000 items where each item can be a random integer in the range from 1 to 10:

```
import random
my_list = [random.randint(1, 10) for x in range(0, 1000)]
```

Then, let's count how many 1s, 2s, 3s, ..., 10s there are in `my_list`:

```
count = [my_list.count(i+1) for i in range(0, 10)]
```

Now `count` is a list like:

| Number of 1s | Number of 2s | ... | Number of 10s |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 32 | 21 | ... | 43 |

If you want to print (python 3.x):

```
for idx, number in enumerate(count):
    print(f'There are {number} item of {idx+1}s')
```